# Simba connector - SSIS - BigQuery - Preview works but no columns are mapped

Tags: ssis, google-bigquery

I have downloaded the Simba ODBC connector from the BigQuery page (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/).

When I create a ODBC source using the connection created with the Simba driver, I can preview the data fine but then when I go to "Columnns" to see the data there is nothing.

[Preview Working Showing Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAoQx.png)

[Column not showing in ODBC source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjjRw.png)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the logs?

Comment: I have just enable logging at the Trace level and that was way too much info.
Now with just the Error logging I get the following
`Sep 23 10:22:49.339 ERROR 29676 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLGetInfoW: [Simba][ODBC] (11180) SQLGetInfo property not found: 1750
Sep 23 10:22:49.340 ERROR 29676 Simba::ODBC::Statement::SQLSetStmtAttrW: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 1228
Sep 23 10:22:49.340 ERROR 29676 Simba::ODBC::Statement::SQLSetStmtAttrW: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 1227`

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue.